# jQuery How to make text fit entire screen width using for loop?

Tags: jquery

My first problem is the code below doesn't work as expected, any simple fix so I can style div element inside jQuery?

```
$('div').css({
  'display':'inline-block'
});
```

Next I thought by using a same-width font like Consolas and making all text 16px then dividing screen width by 16 I would be able to fit text on the screen without any overflow. It didn't work however, it only reached a little over half screen. Here is the code so far.

```
$('*').css({
  'font-family':'consolas',
  'font-size':'16px',
  'margin':'0',
  'padding':'0'
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width() / 16;
  for (var i = 0; i < windowWidth; i++) {
    $('body').append('<div>0</div>')
  }
});
```

Comment: what happens with your first problem? (ie what's expected and what happens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**: the loop count is specified

Using a for loop you can use this fiddle, the font in question doesn't need to be fixed width.

```js
var t = $('.wide'), // target div
  w = t.width(), // get container width or window size replace 't' with $(window)
  text = t.text(), // use existing div text as the template
  more = ''; // define the growing string

t.wrapInner("<span></span>"); // we can get the width of a span wrapped around text
var spans = t.find(':first'), // define the span variable
    count = Math.floor( w / spans.width() ); // work out how many times to repeat

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  more += text; // append to the string
  spans.text(more); // update the text
  $('.output').text('window width ' + w); // feedback
  $('.monitor').text('characters added ' + i); //feedback
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='wide'>0</div>
<div class='output'></div>
<div class='monitor'></div>
```

Comment: Would be nice to make the code usable for multiple `.wide` (since you use a class)

Answer (score 0):

A reusable micro **jQuery plugin** where you can pass arguments like:

```js
$("h1").lineOfChars("O", 26);      // Character, Font Size
$("#test1").lineOfChars("X", 60);
$("#test2").lineOfChars("t", 18);
```

```css
body{margin:0;}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<div id="test1"></div>
<p id="test2"></p>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Create a line of characters
$.fn.lineOfChars = function(ch, size) {

  var $ln = $("<span/>", {
      text: ch,                          // Insert our character
      appendTo: this,                    // Append to our plugin selector
      css: {fontSize: size, overflow:"hidden",textAlign:"center"}
    }),
    elW = this.innerWidth(),
    lnW = $ln.outerWidth(true),
    tot = Math.floor(elW/lnW),           // Calculate how many characters fit
    line = "";                           // Prepare empty string to hold all characters
  
  if(tot>0) while(tot--) line += ch;     // Concatenate characters
  $ln.css({display:"block"}).text(line); // Add all characters to our span

}
</script>
```